# load image from filesystem in flex

Tags: apache-flex, image, filesystems, load

i have the following:

```
<s:Image  source="{path}/imageName"/>
```

how can i determine that path to load the image from filesystem lets say from
C:\Users\sstauross\Desktop ??

Comment: Are you asking how to determine what the value for the path variable should be?  How would we know; you're building the app and have provided no information about your directory structure.  It is highly unusual to try to load an image into the app using a filesystem URL like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to what i was looking was very simple because i put

```
<s:Image  source="C:\Users\sstauross\Desktop\imageName"/>
```

instead of

```
<s:Image  source="C:/Users/sstauross/Desktop/imageName"/>
```

notice the "\" instead of "/"...

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Edit : If you want to select a specific path, the user will have to confirm the path himself first using the FileSystemList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var userPath:String;

            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                userPath = fsList.selectedPath;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <mx:FileSystemList id="fsList"/>

    <s:Label text="{fsList.selectedPath}"/>

    <s:Button label="Confirm folder selection" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

---

Here's one way to do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var desktopPath:String;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                desktopPath = File.desktopDirectory.nativePath.toString();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Image source="{desktopPath}/myFile.jpg"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: but i want it to work with any local path they give me... I just know that the path is local i dont know if it is C:\Users\sstauross\Desktop or just C:\ for example.. any idea?

Comment: @sstauross so is this new solution what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jivago do you know how can I load a class image through s:image ?
this function is well used in mx:image